# Jquery fadeout text insde a text box and textarea

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Hi this should be a really easy problem but i am stuck.  Is it possible to fade out the text inside a text box and textarea and leave the actual element in place.  I have tried fading out using .html() .val() etc but the element that the text is in is always faded too.

Answer (score 5):

I think the only way to achieve this is by manipulating the input element's colour. Check out the [**JQuery color plugin**](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) that specializes in colour manipulations.

It should work along the lines of

```
$(formelement).animate({ color: "#FFFFFF" }, 600);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the suggestion.  i tried to change it to white and then just remove the val() but it didnt really fade to the white color

Comment: Can you post an on-line example to check out?

Answer (score 1):

Simply surround the text in a span and fade the span. JQuery will fade the element, this is the easiest way. I am not sure there is a way to fade just text and not the entire DOM element.

Edit: Didn't read the textarea part.  To do this you'll probably want to hide the actual input element and style a new one to look like a text element, and then fade the text inside it.  This is commonly done to restyle the look of an input element.

Comment: thanks ill try that - i just assumed there would be an easy way of doing it.