# jQuery: Applying effects to a textbox contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, effects

I am trying to fade out and fade in the text inside a textbox.

Is this even possible with jQuery or javascript?
Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297077/jquery-fadeout-text-insde-a-text-box-and-textarea or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066434/fade-out-text-value-inside-of-text-field-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [jQuerUI color animate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).